# Change component template dynamically

Tags: angularjs

if the template already rendered on screen

how do i change the template in a component (not in ui-router)

i know we can change

```
$state.template = anotherlayout
$state.reload()
```

but is it possible to change current template in component ?

```
import login from './login.html'

.component('app', {
    template,
    controller
})


function template () {
    return login
}

function controller ($scope) {
  $scope.changeTemplate = function () {
      // some code to change template in component
  }
}

controller.$inject = ['$scope']
```

i have tried change $scope.$root.template, but nothing happen